# Freemarker directory path is not readable in UAT

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm using freemarker template to create a pdf file. This code works in my local but when I deploy to UAT, it gives the below error:

```
| ERROR | PrintServlet       | /templates does not exist.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /templates does not exist.
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:128)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:125)
        at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:101)
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(Configuration.java:1171)
        at com.abg.wizardgui.servlet.PrintServlet.processRequest(PrintServlet.java:256)
        at com.abg.wizardgui.servlet.PrintServlet.doPost(PrintServlet.java:420)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at com.abg.wizardgui.filter.JsessionIdRemoverFilter.doFilter(JsessionIdRemoverFilter.java:88)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3706)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Code:

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/templates/"));
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
```

The `template.ftl` file is located inside `src/templates/` folder. I tried multiple ways of defining the directory. I also tried using the setClassForTemplateLoading method instead but it keeps giving an error.

Comment: I assume your code is highly simplified, but just to prevent copy-pasting errors and such, one should not set the template loader just before getting a template. Because, configuration should happen only once, earlier, and `getTemplate` is called after that for multiple times.

Comment: Also your template directory is an absolute path, `"/templates/"`, so it doesn't look for `src/templates`, but `templates` in the root directory. But anyway, anything with `src` will not work either; see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` directory doesn't exist on the server after deployment (at least normally), since it's source code. Instead, you could put your templates under `src/main/resources/templates` (assuming Maven or usual Gradle project structure), so that it will be part of the deployed `jar`. Then use `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(SomeClassFromTheSameJar.class, "/templates")`.